# SQL needed: sum over values by month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with values like this:

```
count1   count2  count3  month
12        1       4       01/12/2011
6         5       4       23/12/2011
14        6       9       11/06/2011
8         5       4       19/06/2011
```

How do I get the following results?

```
count1   count2  count3  month
18        6       8       12
22        11      13      06
```

Comment: What is the discriminator here? What differntiates first set of result from second, is that month column or something else?

Comment: Please, give an example of your resultant Table, relating to the First table. So, that any one can understand easily what you want.

Answer (score 33):

```
SELECT SUM(count1), SUM(count2), SUM(count3), MONTH(month)
  FROM myTable
 GROUP BY MONTH(month)
```

Since `MONTH` is an SQL Server keyword, you might have to escape the column name `month` (e.g. `[month]`), if your date column is really called like that. (Thanks Endy for that comment!)

Also, if data selected span more than one year, you will probably need to group by year as well:

```
SELECT SUM(count1), SUM(count2), SUM(count3), MONTH(month), YEAR(month)
  FROM myTable
 GROUP BY MONTH(month), YEAR(month)
```

Comment: You may want to escape that column name into [month]

Answer (score 2):

**reduce the query burden**

```
SELECT SUM(count1), SUM(count2), SUM(count3), substring(month,4,2)   
FROM myTable  
GROUP BY substring(month,4,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(count1), SUM(count2), SUM(count3), MONTH(month)   
FROM Table  
GROUP BY trunc(month,'mm')
```

This will run in PL/SQL developer :)

Comment: But it wont run on SQL Server, which is what he is using (according to the tags anyway).

Comment: ya mike ..may be it wont.. :)

Comment: But it's always nice to get the daily dose of PL/SQL, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(count1) as sum_count1,
to_char(month, 'yyyy-MM') as month
FROM
dataframe 
GROUP BY
month
```