# select sum of a column between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i want `select` sum of `p_amount` every day on `Payments` table taht `p_date` between `@startdate` and `@enddate`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Payments](
    [p_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(100000,1) NOT NULL,
    [p_amount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [p_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [p_creditor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_debtor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_type] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Payments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED )
```

i want get like follow

```
sum                     day
---------------------------------
30                 2013-07-01
40                 2013-07-02
...                 ....
10                 2013-07-19
```

Comment: SUM and GROUP BY (with appropriate WHERE). This has been asked many times and this question is no different and doesn't show any research effort...

Comment: can you refrence me to same question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618748/sql-sum-of-values-between-two-dates-calculated-fields/17622169#17622169 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741212/sql-needed-sum-over-values-by-month/5741226#5741226 etc. any GROUP BY question is exactly about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, p_date)) [date],
       SUM(p_amount) [sum]
  FROM tbl_Payments
 WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, p_date)) BETWEEN '20130701' AND '20130731'
 GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, p_date))
```

Sample output:

```
|                        DATE | SUM |
-------------------------------------
| July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  22 |
| July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  30 |
| July, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  35 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33c70/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with sql-server query but the query for your question is Something like this

```
SELECT    sum(p_amount) as sum, CONVERT(date, getdate()) as day
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN [day1] AND [day2] group by day
```