# creating summation in a sql table in SSIS for Tableau

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, tableau-api

I want to sum hours for daily dates by month in an ssis package. I wrote the following sql code for this:

The below query calculates the sum of ForecastHoursEnd and groups the date by month

```
select year(forecastdate) as y, month(forecastdate) as m,sum(ForecastHrsEnd) as p
from rpt_histsnapeng
group by year(forecastdate), month(forecastdate)
```

and,
The below query calculates the sum of Actual Hours and groups the date by month

```
select year(ActualsDate) as y, month(ActualsDate) as m, sum(ActualHrs) as p
from rpt_histsnapeng
group by year(ActualsDate), month(ActualsDate)
```

Now I am trying to write the code in SSIS to pass them to a variable/column so that I can use that column in Tableau to create a chart,  how would I do that?

I was referencing the following links for this purpose:

[SQL needed: sum over values by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741212/sql-needed-sum-over-values-by-month)
and
[SQl query to sum-up amounts by month/year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974383/sql-query-to-sum-up-amounts-by-month-year)

Comment: What is the output you are looking to get?

Comment: something like this:  rpt_HistsnapEng has forecastdate, forecast hours, actuals date and actuals hours for daily dates. I want to sum the hours for actual hours and forecast hours by month for the entire year

Comment: Are you trying to combine the results from the two queries into a single result that you would be able to use in Tableau?

Comment: yes like the 2 results can be stored as values in two different column and then I will be creating a line chart on forecast date to show 2 lines viz actual hours and forecast hours

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the table? It appears these dates are separate columns in the same table, correct? Something like: `ForecastDate | ActualsDate | ForecaseHrsEnd | ActualHrs`

Comment: yes exactly..SELECT
      ,[ForecastDate]
      ,[ActualsDate]
      ,[ForecastHrsEnd]
      ,[ActualHrs]
  FROM [dbo].[RPT_HistSnapEng_temp]

Comment: Thanks. So to answer your question about why we are not doing this in Tableau is because there are large number of columns in the database and this takes up a lot of time for the tableau dashboard to load

Comment: Do you need/use all of the columns in the database? You can tell Tableau to only read in the columns that you want. Additionally, _sometimes_ extracting the data to a Tableau Data Extract (.tde) can help local performance.

Answer (score 0):

**First, there is no reason at all you can't just use Tableau to perform your aggregations at the year and month grain - without having to pre-aggregate the data.**

However, if you insist on preparing the data in SQL first, you have a couple of options:

**1. UNION**

This is a more normalized structure that will allow you to use `t` ("type") in as the measure to separate/delineate your data.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(ForecastDate) AS y,
    MONTH(ForcastDate) AS m,
    'Forecast' AS t,
    SUM(ForecastHrsEnd) AS p
FROM
    rpt_histsnapeng
GROUP BY
    YEAR(ForecastDate),
    MONTH(ForcastDate)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    YEAR(ActualsDate) AS y,
    MONTH(ActualsDate) AS m,
    'Actual' AS t,
    SUM(ActualHrs) AS p
FROM
    rpt_histsnapeng
GROUP BY
    YEAR(ActualsDate),
    MONTH(ActualsDate)
```

**2. BASIC**

This is denormalized and closer to the existing table structure. Tableau can handle this design nicely, as well, by simply using the measures (hours) as dual axes.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(ForecastDate) AS Forecast_Year,
    MONTH(ForcastDate) AS Forecast_Month,
    YEAR(ActualsDate) AS Actual_Year,
    MONTH(ActualsDate) AS Actual_Month,
    SUM(ForecastHrsEnd) AS Forecast_Hours,
    SUM(ActualHrs) AS Actual_Hours
FROM
    rpt_histsnapeng
GROUP BY
    YEAR(ForecastDate),
    MONTH(ForcastDate),
    YEAR(ActualsDate),
    MONTH(ActualsDate)
```